Latreia: origins?
The idea of Latreia (Greek) or Latria (Latin) was brought up in a separate thread (see Why is προσκυνέω translated as "worship" only when applied to God but not when applied to men?) on the translation of the Hebrew and Greek terms for bowing down - and how translators tend to translate the term as “worship” when applied to God / a god / Christ / Etc, but translate it literally as “bow down” when applied to, say, a human king.
It would appear that Latreia is defined to be a special type of veneration which is reserved only for God - which would explain the source for the argument that if Jesus received worship then he must be God. It is in fact a simple deduction (but one that relies upon selective mistranslation).
I am now interested in better understanding the origins and arguments for Latreia. Are there any instances of the term in scripture? Which Church Fathers first put forth the idea, and were there any debates around the idea?
Although Protestants seem to be unwitting recipients of the idea of Latreia, the concept appears to be much more well defined in both Catholicism and Eastern Orthodoxy. The question is open to all - but answers should focus on the origins of the concept first and foremost.

I do not see any merit in pursuing this line of inquiry. Clearly the concept of 'homage' or 'veneration' takes its particular nuance in the context in which it is used. Rendered to God, there will be a different expression and intention than when the same concept is rendered to men on earth. I cannot see why there is a question about this obvious contextual application of the broader concept. Underlying the argument is a motive to deny worship by men to the Son of God. But proper consideration of the concept and its varied application makes the matter clear.

@NigelJ people often don’t see value in pursuing line of inquiries which challenge their own positions. The fact remains that where you insist upon a distinction, the scriptures use the same verb both when the action is directed at man and when it is directed at God. And to use that distinction as a basis for translation is to inject your own biases and preconceived views into the scriptures. That is especially evidenced by translating the term differently when applied to Christ and then using that difference in translation as a proof of him being God Almighty. It is circular logic

Indeed. That is the exact point I am making. There are some who see (by their faith) that whom the Son of God is, is deserving of a particular kind of 'homage' (that appropriate to Deity). But others do not see that in him, and therefore they offer the other kind of 'homage'. The same word is used. But the scope of the word covers both. The beauty is in the eye of the beholder.

@NigelJ then it should be translated as written rather than attempting to commit the sin of eisegesis to try to trick others into thinking that’s what scripture actually says. Make your arguments without manipulating the word of God

That was entirely my point in my first comment.

@NigelJ you sure? Because reading it again it still looks like you are defending the current corruption of the text

You now seem to be implying there is 'corruption' in the  text of scripture. Or did you mean to say 'translation' ? No matter ; we are going nowhere on this, so I shall cease to comment.

@NigelJ I mean the translations - which is what the vast majority of people rely upon to read the scriptures. They are effectively one in the same - especially when this practice is employed across all modern translations. There are a couple older english translations that don't do this - like the Wycliffe Bible.

But the Wycliffe is translated from the Latin Vulgate not the Koine Greek text. Therefore, see @Anne 's answer which properly catalogues the real issues.

@NigelJ It is translated from the vulgate - but it is simply the same situation. The same verb is used for both God and man - only Wycliffe translated consistently. And Anne cannot substantiate her answer - it is obviously false. Koine isn’t a Christian language - let alone a Trinitarian one - that bowing down came to mean a form of worship reserved for the one true God in the 1st century AD. But if you all can substantiate it I will eat my shirt

Splendid ! I bid you Bon appetit.

Cough up the proof first. Don’t know why you are getting so excited over an obviously false answer.

Can you edit in a link to the thread you mention at the beginning of your question?

@MikeBorden added!

The origins of latreia seem to be in Classical Greek. The Greek language stems from Ancient Greek which was from the 14th to the 12th centuries B.C. Then came Archaic Greek until 800 B.C. That was followed by Classical Greek until 400 B.C. Next was Hellenistic Greek, the common language of Greece, Asia Minor, West Asia, and Egypt to the 4th century A.D. Next, Byzantine Greek until the 15th century, and still the ecclesiastical language of the Greek Orthodox Church.
The source I am using here goes to explain something significant about the difference between Classical Greek and Hellenistic (or, Koine = common) Greek:

“Classical Greek word forms have greatly influenced the English
language, particularly in technical vocabulary. In its earlier phases
Greek was spoken mainly in Greece, the islands, the west coast of Asia
Minor, and in colonies in Sicily, the Italian mainland, and south
France. Hellenistic Greek was an important language not only in the
Near East but also in the Roman Empire generally, and is the form also
known as New Testament Greek (in which the gospels and other books of
the New Testament of the Bible were first written.)” The Hutchinson
Softback Encyclopedia, p. 365, Random Century, 1991

That is why the New Testament does not use the much older word ‘latreia’ but uses ‘proskenoo’ to speak of acts of worship of God, and also acts of respectful obeisance. And that is also why it can be questionable to try to import a far older meaning into the words selected by the Holy Spirit in forming the New Testament. For example, there are those who like to turn to Classical Greek to support their modern English translations of the New Testament. This point is significant if some start pushing for emphasis of the “status of a hired servant” in order to dilute the act of worship of Jesus Christ, even when he was on Earth, shown for example when Thomas met the risen Christ, and exclaimed, “My Lord and my God”. Those who adamantly teach that Christ must never be worshiped say Thomas was not actually worshiping. They use the ‘lesser’ meaning.
New Testament Greek can certainly mean respectful bowing before a person of higher status, but it also means worship of the one true God. And that was clearly commanded in the Hebrew scriptures, so that Christians would understand perfectly well the difference between worshiping God (whether or not bowing down was involved) and respect given in demeanor shown to other humans. In Hebrews 1:6, where most translations say of Christ, “Let all God’s angels worship him”, others who look to Classical Greek say, “Let all God’s angels do obeisance to him”. Yet a bit further on in Hebrews that same word is used of elderly Joseph, who was dying. He is said to have worshipped, leaning on his staff (11:21). The Greek word is proskenoo. But clearly it does include worship because Joseph could not physically bow down; he was too elderly and too near death! So he worshipped God while leaning on his staff. Sadly, some translations today never speak of Christ as being worshipped, but take the Classical Greek sense of mere respectful bowing, obeisance, every time Jesus is the object of proskeoo.
Yet in Revelation, when the Apostle John falls prostrate before the risen Christ, he is not rebuked for going too far; unlike the angel who rebuked John later on for doing that to him. Compare Rev. 1:17 with 22:8-9. Christ accepts worship (whether or not that involves being prostrate). It is the same worship due to God, for Christ shares divine nature with the Father, with absolute unity of the Spirit in that nature. That kind of worship is way above what the Classical Greek word latreia had in view, for polytheism was its mindset.

Can you substantiate the idea that for Koine Greek specifically that the meaning of these verbs changed? For instance, can you substantiate that it was commonly understood amongst all people in the first century AD that "to bow down" (προσκυνέω) in fact was a an act of worship reserved for the one true God? Was koine an invention of the Jews such that by this point in time not only they but everyone else used the term this way? I have my doubts that you can support such claims.

@RyanPierceWilliams  I’m not saying that all 1st century people took bowing in worship to be reserved only for the God of the Bible. Quite the opposite! Pagans had the looser meaning of worship due to polytheism and supposing some humans were gods. Hence slaves had to bow and scrape to their masters. Kings were actually worshiped as gods as were Roman emperors. But in the OT the Jews knew that only the one true God was to be worshiped. They learned the hard way to stop bowing before idols, finally 'getting it' after deportation to Babylon. That meant that, 400 years after Classical Greek

had been replaced with Hellenistic Greek, they already knew the difference between exclusive worship of God, and respect shown to humans when bowing before rulers. Nobody else seemed to. Neither Jews nor Christians ever changed meanings in Greek language. Both senses (worship and respectful bowing) were covered by proskenoo, but they worshiped God exclusively. When they bowed to rulers they were not worshiping them. The pagans all around had their ideas about worship given indiscriminately to their many gods and to all who demanded it. Not God’s people. They stuck to the OT sense which is why

Daniel’s 3 friends got thrown into the furnace. That is why Christians who refused to put a pinch of incense on the emperor’s altar, calling him ‘Lord’, were thrown to the lions. They knew the meaning of Ceasar’s coin as Jesus said; to give tax, honour etc as due to Ceasar, but to give to God what is his – exclusive worship. Bowing down is only worship if the person doing it does so as an act of worship, no matter what the language is, or how it’s understood by pagans. This is not about language but of what God demands of his people; exclusive worship. But for those who want to include others

in their adoration, using the lesser meaning of Classical Greek gives scope. Equally, for those who want to exclude Jesus from their worship, using Koine Greek can also appear to justify them. But the Bible’s meaning is not dependent on any branch of language in the past, or the present. It is crystal clear as to how God views worship, and God's people know the difference between that and pagan adoration.

You realize that in the Septuagint, the koine translation of the OT, that the term προσκυνέω is used towards men, right? For example, when Moses bowed to Jethro. You need to actually provide evidence for your ideas and not just insist things are how you want them to be.


The noun λατρεια (latreia), meaning (paid) service or service for a wage. Technically, this noun describes servitude or the state of a hired laborer, but in the New Testament, this noun describes solely man's service to God (implying that all the blessings of life and intellect are in fact the wage for which service is due). - Abarim Publications

This noun is used 5 times in the New Testament:

They shall put you out of the synagogues: yea, the time cometh, that whosoever killeth you will think that he doeth God service.- John 16:2
Who are Israelites; to whom [pertaineth] the adoption, and the glory, and the covenants, and the giving of the law, and the service [of God,] and the promises - Romans 9:4
I beseech you therefore, brethren, by the mercies of God, that ye present your bodies a living sacrifice, holy, acceptable unto God, [which is] your reasonable service. - Romans 12:1
Then verily the first [covenant] had also ordinances of divine service, and a worldly sanctuary. - Hebrews 9:1
Now when these things were thus ordained, the priests went always into the first tabernacle, accomplishing the service [of God. ] - Hebrews 9:6

The noun comes from the verb λατρευω (latreuo) meaning:

to serve, but with an emphasis on hire (rather than serving out of passion). It is not related to the familiar noun latrine (which is a contraction of lavatrina, from lavare, to wash). It's used 21 times in the New Testament:

There is a note at the top of this concordance listing which says; "This word inflects according to its grammatical function and context, and thus comes in various forms.".  Rather than list all 21 occurances (which can be found in the link given above) I will point out three which contextually show the range available of who or what may be served (latreuo):

Then saith Jesus unto him, Get thee hence, Satan: for it is written, Thou shalt worship the Lord thy God, and him only shalt thou serve. - Matthew 4:10
Then God turned, and gave them up to worship the host of heaven; as it is written in the book of the prophets, O ye house of Israel, have ye offered to me slain beasts and sacrifices [by the space of] forty years in the wilderness? - Acts 7:42
We have an altar, whereof they have no right to eat which serve the tabernacle. - Acts 13:10

Thus, this verb means "to serve" and it is context which indicates whom or what is being served.  The same service, which rightly belongs to God may be offered to idols, or the host of heaven, or an obsolete religious system.
Neither this verb, nor the noun it fosters, nor the noun it stems from are ever used with Christ clearly presented as the person served.  This poses little problem for trinitarians who see, within the word God, Father, Son, and Spirit equally embedded and represented.

There is another verb, δουλευω (douleuo), meaning to be a servant, to render a service, to work or be working class and this verb is used in the context of men serving both God and the Lord Christ.  "No servant can serve (douleuo) two masters" and "Knowing that of the Lord ye shall receive the reward of the inheritance: for ye serve the Lord Christ."

A separate question regarding the word translated as "worship", προσκυνεω (proskuneo) might be profitable.  It is this word in Matthew 4:10:

Then saith Jesus unto him, Get thee hence, Satan: for it is written, Thou shalt worship (proskuneo) the Lord thy God, and him only shalt thou serve (latreuo).

So Jesus has told Satan to worship God only and later, in Hebrews 1:6, we can see that God has commanded His angels (of which order is Lucifer) to worship Jesus:

And again, when he bringeth in the firstbegotten into the world, he saith, And let all the angels of God worship (proskuneo) him.


Great information, thank you :) I will only quibble over one point, which is the bit at the end about proskuneo. Matthew 4:10 does not say to worship God alone. It says to only serve (latreuo) him. No verse in scripture asserts that "worship" (proskuneo) is reserved for God alone - at least none that I have been able to find.

@RyanPierceWilliams Thanks.  Unless the kai is copulative:  Worship and serve Him only.  I just asked this over on BH:  https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/100041/32868

The intent can be clarified by the OT which he is here referring to. If you can find a spot in the OT where “worship” is said to be reserved for God alone then you might be able to make an argument over the potential range of meaning of the Greek.

@RyanPierceWilliams One of those answers makes a good case that the OT "phrase bow down and serve only" is what Jesus had in mind.

I've reviewed all the answers thus far and I must heartily disagree. The answer in question fails to account for the wealth of counter-evidence - like how King David received "worship" along with God from the people in 1 Chronicles 29:20. And, at any rate, in my answer I pick apart the Greek and demonstrate that "only" is an adjective describing "him" - and does not apply grammatically to the act of "worship" in the Greek. Don't pick an answer because you want it to be right - follow the evidence.

@RyanPierceWilliams  If the lack of distinction that you see (and which, on the surface, is actually there; i.e. David does indeed receive "worship") is all there is to it then there would be nothing wrong with "worshiping" idols or false gods as long as only God is served.  It is this that produces the necessity for a distinction in the "worship" that belongs to God alone.

There are commands against bowing down to idols and serving other gods; there is no need to create new terminology to communicate this

@RyanPierceWilliams If there are commands against bowing down to idols (and false gods?) doesn't that mean that a command to bow down to God alone is implied?

No it does not follow that a command not to bow down to idols, the works of human hands, means that such an act is reserved for God alone. There are numerous examples in scripture of men bowing down to other men. Moses bows to his father-in-law. The people bow to the prophet Elisha when he succeeds Elijah. The assembly bows down simultaneously and pays homage to both King David and to God Almighty. Never is this rebuked as inappropriate or sinful.

@RyanPierceWilliams Those examples are granted.  Is your supposition that Moses bowing to his father-in-law is equivalent to Moses bowing to God?  If the people bowed to Elisha identically to how they bow to God would that not be sinful?  Did the people bow to God and David equally or just simultaneously?  Or is your supposition that God approves of service done to Himself absent worship [bowing down]?

@RyanPierceWilliams "Bowing down" to the President of the United States (all the while thinking he disgraces the office) and "bowing down" to the President of the United States (all the while believing that he is the best President ever) are equivalent on the surface only.  The former is not in Spirit and in Truth but is, instead, hypocrisy.

“bowing down” is an action that maybe applied to man or to God, as scripture attests. The action doesn’t change based upon who is receiving the action; that’s not how language works. We don’t need distinct terms for the same action just because one is greater than the other; such concerns are clarified by the larger scriptural context without the need to artificially introduce distinctions in our terminology not found in the original languages. The addition of such distinctions is a corruption of the text

whether one’s act of bowing be considered hypocritical or not - it is still the same action. You confuse the spirit in which an action is done for the action itself; these are separate issues

@RyanPierceWilliams Sure, and the Spirit in which it is done is primary.  Honoring with the lips with a distant heart is not commended.  "Bowing down" on the mountain or in Jerusalem takes a back seat to "bowing down" in Spirit and Truth.  Do you not see that one can bow down (worship) God in Spirit and Truth without any specific actual bodily posture change?

when it comes to translation - no, the spirit in which something is done is not primary. The primary concern of translation is to faithfully communicate what is written; for any analysis of the text (such as discerning the spirit in which a given action is performed) is dependent upon a faithful translation first and foremost.

@RyanPierceWilliams The verb carries both a literal and a figurative meaning.  Context determines where the verb should land on this spectrum. A faithful translation will accommodate both senses and bring them to bear appropriately because that is part of faithfully communicating what is written.  Jesus did this very thing in conversation with the Samaritan woman, He rightly divided the Word.

Even if there were a figurative meaning behind the action of bowing down in a given context, you would still translate it as bowing down; the job of translation is to faithfully transmit what is written - not to interpret for the reader. And, at any rate, "worship" with its added idea of being reserved for God alone is never on that spectrum of meaning. That is purely a corruption that we have introduced in modernity - not a meaning found in the text.

@RyanPierceWilliams "Understanding translation philosophy is important when interpreting the Bible. You will learn about the first principle of interpretation which involves determining the meaning of words by looking at the word's immediate context, broader context, and historical and cultural context.".  A good test is to see how the Apostolic Fathers used the text, since they were still actively fluent in the language in question.

you are welcome to attempt to show that the early Church Fathers selectively translated the word as “worship” - only problem is that it is a unique English term that reflects later theological usage and doesn’t reflect any term in the original languages. But good luck in trying to substantiate your position

Latreia: origins?
Although latreia basically means the veneration due to God alone for his supreme excellence; its origins are a little more complex.

Latria
The veneration due to God alone for his supreme excellence and to show people's complete submission to him. It is essentially adoration. As absolute latria, it is given only to God, as the Trinity, or one of the Divine Persons, Christ as God and as man, the Sacred Heart of Jesus, and the Holy Eucharist. Representations of God as images connected with the Divinity may receive relative latria, which is given not to the symbol but to the Godhead, whom it signifies. (Etym. Greek latreiā, service, worship.)

The term latria in classical Greek originally meant "the state of a hired servant".

Latria
Latria (latreia) in classical Greek originally meant "the state of a hired servant" (Aesch., "Prom.", 966), and so service generally. It is used especially for Divine service (Plato, "Apol.", 23 B). In Christian literature it came to have a technical sense for the supreme honour due to His servants, the angels and saints. This latter was styled "dulia". Etymologically, however, there is no reason why latria should be preferred to designate supreme honour; and indeed the two words were often used indiscriminately. The distinction is due to St. Augustine, who says: "Latria . . . ea dicitur servitus quae pertinet ad colendum Deum" (City of God X.1).


Aha, so it’s Augustine whom I need to study more. I have read the City of God before - though I admit I have a hard time staying focused reading his lengthy volumes. This gives me a good place to start digging into the matter more - thank you :)
